# Scala Spark Geospatial Intersection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe Polyline with schema :

```
|-- Polyline_id: string (nullable = false)
|-- latitude: double(nullable = true)
|-- longitude: double(nullable = true)
|-- point_index: integer(nullable = true)
```

Polyline contains multiple rows for each element 'Polyline_id'.

And a dataframe Segments with schema :

```
|-- Segments_id: string (nullable = false)
|-- latitudeStart: double(nullable = true)
|-- longitudeStart: double(nullable = true)
|-- latitudeEnd: double(nullable = true)
|-- longitudeEnd: double(nullable = true)
```

Segments contains only one row for each element 'Segments_id'

I want to generate a new dataframe that contains for all 'Segments_id', the list of 'Polyline_id' that intersect that Segment

One solution is to generate a new dataframe of segments SegmentsFromPoly from the dataframe Polyline and comparing all the segments of SegmentsFromPoly with those from Segments thanks to a UDF.

I am looking for a simpler and more efficient method for that (if it does exist !).

### Sample datas :

Polyline :

```
"poly_id_1",25.254,55.400,1
"poly_id_1",25.258,55.394,2
"poly_id_1",25.261,55.390,3
"poly_id_2",25.284,55.450,1
"poly_id_2",25.298,55.392,2
"poly_id_2",25.305,55.300,3
```

Segments :

```
"seg_id_1",25.253,55.405,25.280,55.380
"seg_id_2",25.993,55.405,25.549,55.941
"seg_id_3",25.237,55.489,25.357,55.785
"seg_id_4",25.894,55.719,25.197,55.354
```

Output :

```
"seg_id_1",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_1",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_2",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_3",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_3",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_4",[a poly_id]
"seg_id_4",[a poly_id]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Magellan](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan) which supports [spatial joins](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan#spatial-joins) using [geohash indexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).

To make it work you'll have to include the package and inject Magellan optimization rules. Please follow [the documentation](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan) for details.